# How to create an individual of a specific class from SPARQL query using Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, fuseki

I am using insert data query to create an individual in this way

```
PREFIX d: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/hecproject.owl#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
INSERT Data
{
d:new2 d:hasUniversityName "Namal" .
d:University a rdfs:Class .
}
```

I am assuming that `d:University` is telling the query that created individual `new2` is of type University class. When I execute the query it works fine and inserts a record in the dataset and when I execute a general query like this

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```

then individual is created but when i try to find all individuals of class University i do not find it like that was not created with class University?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please consider reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 1):

You're **not** assigning the individual `d:new2` to the class `d:University` in your INSERT query. All your query does it to add exactly the two triples

```
d:new2 d:hasUniversityName "Namal" .
d:University a rdfs:Class .
```

nothing more, nothing less.

Indeed it's up to you to the triple

```
d:new2 rdf:type d:University .
```

that assigns `d:new2` to class `d:University`:

```
PREFIX d: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/hecproject.owl#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
INSERT Data {
 d:new2 d:hasUniversityName "Namal" .
 d:new2 rdf:type d:University .
 d:University a rdfs:Class .
}
```